# trying to overwrite 'file' which is also in package 'name'

Tags: apt, dependencies

After I added this ppa ***ppa:thopiekar/darling*** and tried to install ***darling*** without success, I can't fix anything with the *sudo apt-get install -f install* command

```
jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for jeggy: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gnustep-gui
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnustep-gui
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3.569 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12,4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 283062 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking gnustep-gui:amd64 (from .../gnustep-gui_0.23.1-0~201311190000~7545~7~ubuntu13.10.1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gnustep-gui_0.23.1-0~201311190000~7545~7~ubuntu13.10.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/GNUstep/ColorPickers/StandardPicker.bundle/StandardPicker', which is also in package gnustep-gui-runtime 0.22.0-1ubuntu1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gnustep-gui_0.23.1-0~201311190000~7545~7~ubuntu13.10.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~$
```

Could someone help me to fix this?

Comment: Try to remove the package `gnustep-gui-runtime`...

Comment: I'm not so good with the command line, how do i remove it?

Comment: I removed it using Synaptic, and it worked :D

Comment: You will have to use the command line tools, see http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/

Answer (score 1):

Well, you meet the wrong time to make your install. I decided now to make multiarch builds. So we have dyld64 and dyld32 for mach-o binaries in 32bit and 64bit. In these cases please just wait for a while. I often look to add versions to the dependencies (e.g. gnustep or llvm) to make installing/upgrading to the new package layout work well.

**However, I added now a notice to the PPA page. - My PPA was not ready at all, but many blogs and articles are pointing to it! Nobody asked if it is ready or not!
For all the rest of the people having problems with the PPA: Blame it on the writers of these posts!**

So the best solution is just to purge the package:

`sudo apt-get purge <pkg>`

or when you got the time, wait and do this after hours or days (depending on how fast I am and the launchpad build system builds and releases my packages):

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade -f`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `gnustep-gui-runtime` package to perform the operation:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnustep-gui-runtime
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnustep-gui
```

> trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/GNUstep/ColorPickers/StandardPicker.bundle/StandardPicker', which is also in package gnustep-gui-runtime 0.22.0-1ubuntu1

This message indicates what is happening. At the moment you have 2 packages that tries to provide the same file. I would blame the use of PPA's since package in repositories doesn't have collisions of the files they provide (each of them is stored using different names/paths in case you need to provide the different versions of the same files).

Answer (score 0):

Try this command on terminal,

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/gnustep-gui_0.23.1-0~201311190000~7545~7~ubuntu13.10.1_amd64.deb
```

dpkg forcely overwrites the `StandardPicker` file present in `/usr/lib/GNUstep/ColorPickers/StandardPicker.bundle` with it's file from the  `gnustep-gui` package.

Comment: You should really explain what the command does.. no one wants to run a random command.